# Why string indices must be integers only when running as __main__

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that takes a dictionary that looks like this:

```
result = {
    "testsUntaken" = ["format", "structure"],
    "testsFailed" = []
    "testsPassed" = []
    "otherstuff" = "otherstuff"
}
```

This is the function.

```
def take_tests(result):
    """Recursively runs the tests in the testsUntaken list until it is empty"""
    testsList = {
        "format": allowed_file,
        "structure": allowed_structure
    }
    if len(result["testsUntaken"]) > 0:
        test = result["testsUntaken"][0]
        if testsList[test](result):
            result["testsPassed"].append(test)
        else:
            result = rejection(result, test)
        result["testsUntaken"].remove(test)
        result = take_tests(result)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("something unrelated")
```

Much to my surprise, this function works perfectly well when I call it from another file, but when I just try to run something unrelated as "**main**" I get:

```
  File "my_file.py", line 56, in take_tests
    if len(result["testsUntaken"]) > 0:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `take_tests` is never called in your example.

Comment: `def take_tests(result):` - "result" is a local variable unrelated to the global "result" dictionary. Whether the function works is completely dependent on what value you supply to "result" when you call it.

Comment: Correct, I get the error when the function is not called.   When I call it, there is a dictionary with a 'testsUntaken' key.   When I do not, I'd prefer for it to just sit there, but it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a cop-out, but I just rewrote this as a class and it worked fine.  With an initialized result dictionary already on scope there appear to be no problems.